# Can I transform a delimited string to a JSON array using jq?

Tags: json, jq, csvtoarray

I'm writing a script that receives a delimited list of non-jSON data `jq`.  My goal is to transform that list to a JSON array.  The actual data is delimited with commas, but I could easily translate that to delimit by spaces or newlines, if that makes the problem easier.

I obviously can't pass this directly to `jq` since it's not JSON formatted data.

```
$ echo "A,B,C" | jq
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
```

Does `jq` have a way to translate delimited non-JSON data into a JSON array?

## Example

### Input

```
ABC,123,XYZ,A"B,{1}
```

### Output

```json
["ABC", "123", "XYZ", "A\"B", "{1}"]
```

How can I achieve this using `jq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`/`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#multiplication-division-modulo) operator, which splits the first string using the second as a separator, like so:

```sh
jq -cR './","' <<< 'ABC,123,XYZ,A"B,{1}'
```

```json
["ABC","123","XYZ","A\"B","{1}"]
```

Or equivalently, using the [`split`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#split-1) function:

```sh
jq -cR 'split(",")' <<< 'ABC,123,XYZ,A"B,{1}'
```

If you want to use a regex to help with the splitting, consider this example that trims spaces around the commas:

```sh
jq -cR '[splits(" *, *")]' <<< 'ABC, 123, XYZ, A"B, {1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the delimiter to a newline, you can use the `-s` option so that `jq` reads the entire input as if it were a JSON array. Notice the following examples:

```
§ echo $'1\n2\n3' | jq -s
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

```
§ echo $'1\n2\n3' | jq -s 'length'
3
```

Comment: Good to know, though that doesn't work (without modifications) for my example where each line is an arbitrary, non-JSON string